# Angular5 @output decorator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello there learning angular and came across the @output decorators in angular. After researching the topic I still have some difficulty wrapping my head around this concept.

### Code example:

*app.component.html:*

```
<app-tutorials(event)="doSomething($event)"></app-tutorials>
```

*app.component.ts:*

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  doSomething(event){
    alert("being executed");
  }
}
```

*tutorial.component.html:*

```
<button (click)="beingClicked($event)"_>click me</button>
```

*tutorial.component.ts:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tutorials',
  templateUrl: './tutorials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tutorials.component.css']
})
export class TutorialsComponent{

  @Output() event = new EventEmitter();

  beingClicked(event){
    this.event.emit(event);
  }
}
```

My current understanding is this, plz correct me if I'm wrong:

- `output` is used to transfer data only from child components the parent component.
- When the button is clicked `beingClicked(event)` is fired and passes through event info in the argument with $event.
- We can emit the event with `this.event.emit(event);`   because we first instantiated the event earlier in the class with the statement: `@Output() event = new EventEmitter();`
- Now the parent component listens for `(event)` in the app.component.html:`<app-tutorials(event)="doSomething($event)"></app-tutorials>`
- When the `event` is emitted from the child component the `doSomething($event)` function is fired and gets passed in the `$event`

### Question:

1. Is my current understanding correct?
2. What exactly is this EventEmitter and is it always needed to data upwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my current understanding correct?

Your understanding is correct. There are other ways to share data but to notify the parent of an event that needs to be reacted to this is the appropriate way to do it. For more details / examples of component interaction see also the documentation [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).

> What exactly is this EventEmitter and is it always needed to data upwards?

The [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) is an event that other code (components, services, etc.) can subscribe to. The owner of the [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) can then fire the event with data whenever it is appropriate and the code that has subscribed to the event can decide how to handle the call or ignore it all together if it is not relevant. See also [Event-driven Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

It is not necessarily only for upstream (child to parent) it could also be used horizontally (child to child) communication via a shared service dependency or for downstream (also using a shared service dependency) so that child components can decide how to handle an event triggered by a parent component.